# Automation Add-ins for MS Excel 2013

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to write a C# automation add-in in Visual Studio 2013. The objective is to be able to call UDFs written in C# from within MS Excel 2013. I have read most of the publicly available materials on the subject and have tried to adapt several simple examples, [such as](http://pragmateek.com/excel-udf-in-c-from-scratch/).

Unfortunately, neither of them is written under VS 2013 and MSExcel 2013. Code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace MyFirstAddIn
{
// Early binding. Doesn't need AutoDual.
[Guid("5E6CD676-553F-481E-9104-4701C4DAB272")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IFinancialFunctions
{
    double Bid(string symbol);
    double Ask(string symbol);
    double[,] BidnAsk(string symbol, string direction = null);
}

[Guid("B9B7A498-6F84-43EB-A50C-6D26B72895DA")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class FinancialFunctions : IFinancialFunctions
{
    // Private class members.
    private static readonly WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    private const string UrlTemplate = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={0}&f={1}";

    // Private method - data download.
    private static double GetDoubleDataFromYahoo(string symbol, string field)
    {
        string request = string.Format(UrlTemplate, symbol, field);
        string rawData = webClient.DownloadString(request);

        return double.Parse(rawData.Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    // Public "interface" methods.
    public double Bid(string symbol)
    {
        return GetDoubleDataFromYahoo(symbol, "b3");
    }

    public double Ask(string symbol)
    {
        return GetDoubleDataFromYahoo(symbol, "b2");
    }

    public double[,] BidnAsk(string symbol, string direction = null)
    {
        double bid = GetDoubleDataFromYahoo(symbol, "b3");
        double ask = GetDoubleDataFromYahoo(symbol, "b2");

        return direction == "v" ? new[,]{{bid}, {ask}} : new[,]{{bid, ask}};
    }

    [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void RegisterFunction(Type type)
    {
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"));
        RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(GetSubKeyName(type, "InprocServer32"), true);
        key.SetValue("",System.Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\mscoree.dll",RegistryValueKind.String);
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void UnregisterFunction(Type type)
    {
        Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"), false);
    }

    private static string GetSubKeyName(Type type, string subKeyName)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        s.Append(@"CLSID\{");
        s.Append(type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper());
        s.Append(@"}\");
        s.Append(subKeyName);

        return s.ToString();
    }  
}
}
```

I have made the assembly COM-visible via:

> Project->Properties->Application->Assembly Information

and I've also registered COM interop in the "Build" tab.

After building, I can see in the registry that registration was successful and the add-in is registered under the correct GUID. However, when I open Excel and go to Developer->Add-ins->Automation, I cannot see my add-in in the list. I verified that the code I'm posting works with Excel 2010 but for some reason I fail to see my add-in in Excel 2013.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the cause of the problem. Surprisingly, it turns out that Visual Studio does not have the capability to automatically register 64bit dlls under the correct tree in the registry. The solution is not to register the project for COM interop and manually add commands to invoke the 64bit version of RegAsm as a post-build event. The full path and name of the dll need to be included, so unfortunately this is not a fully automated solution.